# Negative subscripts in Bash arrays

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, subscript

After creating a simple bash stack script I encountered an error related to bash arrays.

*From the Bash manual:*

> An indexed array is created automatically if any variable is assigned
>   to using the syntax:
>
> `name[subscript]=value`
>
> name[subscript]=value The subscript is treated as an arithmetic
>   expression that must evaluate to a number. If subscript evaluates to a
>   number less than zero, it is used as an offset from one greater than
>   the array’s maximum index (so a subcript of -1 refers to the last
>   element of the array).

Everything worked perfectly fine on my local machine unfortunately my server environment is slightly different.

The negative subscript worked on Ubuntu 14.04 / GNU bash version 4.3.11(1). However when I tried to run the same script on my server with GNU bash version 4.2.46(1) I encountered the following error:

```
line 46: [-1]: bad array subscript
```

I tried to create an array and call the last element directly from the terminal (not inside the script) and it worked:

```
user@local:~$ arr=( 1 2 3 4 5 )
user@local:~$ echo ${arr[-1]}
5
```

I am kinda confused here. Is there any solution or workaround for this?

Answer (score 3):

Guess what's in the [Bash changelog](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES):

For: *changes between this version, bash-4.3-beta, and the
previous version, bash-4.3-alpha*

> x.  The shell now allows assigning, referencing, and unsetting elements of
>       indexed arrays using negative subscripts (a[-1]=2, echo ${a[-1]}) which
>       count back from the last element of the array.

For: *changes between this version, bash-4.2-alpha,
and the previous version, bash-4.1-release*

> p.  Negative subscripts to indexed arrays, previously errors, now are treated
>       as offsets from the maximum assigned index + 1.

So your test is only reading with negative offsets (okay in ~4.2 and above), but your error stems from an attempt to assign or unset with negative offsets (okay in ~4.3 and above).

Perhaps you can refer to the length of the array and do some math on that with:
(reading) `${arr[${#arr[@]}-1]}` and
(assigning) `arr[${#arr[@]}-1]=last` and
(clearing) `unset arr[${#arr[@]}-1]`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification in this matter. I was indeed trying to unset last element of an array. Is there any other way of doing it? Any solutions, workarounds?

Comment: I was thinking of creating something like:

`array[arrayLength - 1]`

Comment: @Ludi okay I suggested alternative methods of assigning and unsetting the last element.

Comment: Thank you once again. Unfortunately I still have this error. I suppose that it is somehow related to the dynamic array name.

`function stateMachine.pop() {                                  
    : ${1? 'Missing attribute name'}                            
    local attribute="${1}";                                     
    local arrayName=STATE_MACHINE_${attribute};                 #

    if [[ ! $( stateMachine.exist "${arrayName}" ) == 0 ]]; then
        unset "${arrayName}[-1]";
    fi
}`

Comment: @Ludi in your snippet there's still the [-1] subscript. Instead I thought it should read like this: `function stateMachine.pop() { : ${1? 'Missing attribute name'} local attribute="${1}"; local arrayName=STATE_MACHINE_${attribute}; # if [[ ! $( stateMachine.exist "${arrayName}" ) == 0 ]]; then local arrayLength=${#"${arrayName}"[@]};unset "${arrayName}[$arrayLength-1]"; fi }`

Comment: Thank you for your help however it still does not work. After using your resolution I received following error message:

`line 46: ${#{arrayName}[@]}: bad substitution`

I have no clue why is that but I'll keep trying!

Comment: Unfortunately this issue still remains. I will try to simply implement the index to pop and push function which will count the number of array elements. Once again thank you for your help!

Comment: @Ludi hey are you sure you tried `#${arrayName}` and not just `#{arrayName}`?

Comment: I resolved this problem by simply adding index variable to my state machine. It reflects the current number of array's elements. 

`function stateMachine.pop() {
: ${1? 'Missing attribute name'}

  local attribute="${1}";
  local arrayName=STATE_MACHINE_${attribute};

    if [[ ! $( stateMachine.exist "${arrayName}" ) == 0 ]]; then
        unset "${arrayName}[$(( ${attribute}_I - 1 ))]";
        eval "${attribute}_I=$(( ${attribute}_I - 1 ))";
    fi
}`